# Colorize a cell on multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to loop the action "colorize cell S1" on all the sheets except if mentioned in the code.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If (ws.Name <> "COVER") And (ws.Name <> "DATA") And (ws.Name <> "HYP") Then    
            With ws            
                Range("S1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)           
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

The macro colorizes only the active sheet, even when the activesheet is one of the out of range sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Use Thisworkbook.Worksheets instead Thisworkbook.Sheets as Sheets will also include charts if any and it will fail with your code.

Second: .Range in With ws.

```
Sub test2()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (ws.Name <> "COVER") And (ws.Name <> "DATA") And (ws.Name <> "HYP") Then    
        With ws            
            .Range("S1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)           
        End With
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

EDIT: Additional info:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (ws.Name <> "COVER") And (ws.Name <> "DATA") And (ws.Name <> "HYP") Then    
        With ws            
            .Range("S1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            FirstBlank = .Range("E2:E" & .Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row            
            .Range("E" & FirstBlank).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(HYP!C[3],HYP!C[-4],RC[-2],HYP!C[-1],"">=""&RC[-4],HYP!C,""<=""&RC[-3])"
        End With
    End If
Next ws
```

This will find the first blank cell in the E column of ws  worksheet and put the formula into the found cell. If that's what you need...

Comment: Thanks a lot  :) (Y)

Comment: hello dear, I can't apply the above on this code, any suggestions ?
        
            With ws
                FirstBlank = Range("E2:E" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
                    Range("E" & FirstBlank).Select
                        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _                            "=SUMIFS(HYP!C[3],HYP!C[-4],RC[-2],HYP!C[-1],"">=""&RC[-4],HYP!C,""<=""&RC[-3])"
                
            End With

Comment: 1- You are still missing dot before the range in with 2- Don't Select the cell to set its formula, because you also have to activate the ws (ws.activate). Instead directly set the formula by using: .Range("E" & FirstBlank).FormulaR1C1 = _ "=SUMIFS(HYP!C[3],HYP!C[-4],RC[-2],HYP!C[-1],"">=""&RC[-4],HYP!C,""<=""&RC[-3])" In fact, you should also change the way of finding the next blank cell by using End() function on the Range. It would work but there are other ways that might work better.

Comment: @BATT Are you doing this in the same With above?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped.